# text color in ckeditor 4.5 beta is not showing

Tags: ckeditor

I downloaded ckeditor 4.5 beta and adding font or find plugin in config.js is working well.

But even if I added colorbutton using extraPlugins function and ‘textcolor’ in colors group, text colors is not showing in my Ckeditor toolbar.

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem recently, not matter change toolbar groups configs to what forms, the colorButton is just not showing on the toolbar.

Finally and occasionally I found a `ckeditor` plugin named `colorbutton` and when 
download it, the download pages show the way to activate it like below image

[image]

and it's effect.

Caution: You need download the dependent plugins too showing on the image, and after changing configs please clear your browser's caches